# Accessing same ViewModel in different recyclerViews

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

Activity A and B contains a RecyclerView and hold the data of similar kind, thus they use **Common view model called AViewModel**

**Activity A.java**

```
 @BindingAdapter("bind:adapter")
public static void setAdapter(RecyclerView recyclerView, ArrayList<AViewModel> vm) {
    AdapterA adapter = ((AdapterA) recyclerView.getAdapter());
    if (adapter != null) {
        adapter.clearList();
        adapter.addAll(vm);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**Activity B.java**

```
 @BindingAdapter("bind:adapter")
public static void setAdapter(RecyclerView recyclerView, ArrayList<AViewModel> vm) {
    AdapterB adapter = ((AdapterB) recyclerView.getAdapter());
    if (adapter != null) {
        adapter.clearList();
        adapter.addAll(vm);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Now on launching Activity A the app crashes and shows

> AdapterA cannot be cast to AdapterB

Suspecting the similar method signature for setAdapter.
Any suggestion as what can be the cause of the problem?

**Error logs**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com. .hackthon.listviewpoc, PID: 308
>                                                                                   java.lang.ClassCastException: com. .hackthon.listviewpoc.AdapterA
>   cannot be cast to com. .hackthon.listviewpoc.AdapterB
>                                                                                       at com.hackthon.listviewpoc.ActivityB.setAdapter(ActivityB.java:39)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.hackthon.listviewpoc.databinding.ActivityABinding.executeBindings(ActivityABinding.java:145)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.executeBindingsInternal(ViewDataBinding.java:379)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.executePendingBindings(ViewDataBinding.java:351)
>                                                                                       at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding$6.run(ViewDataBinding.java:178)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.databinding.ViewDataBinding$5.onViewAttachedToWindow(ViewDataBinding.java:146)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:14531)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2836)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1364)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
>                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
>                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: paste your full error log

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining two `@BindingAdapter("bind:adapter")`, just write once and use `instanceof`

```
@BindingAdapter("bind:adapter")
public static void setAdapter(RecyclerView recyclerView, ArrayList<AViewModel> vm) {
    if(recyclerView.getAdapter() instanceof AdapterA){
        AdapterA adapter = ((AdapterA) recyclerView.getAdapter());
        adapter.clearList();
        adapter.addAll(vm);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    else if(recyclerView.getAdapter() instanceof AdapterB){
        AdapterB adapter = ((AdapterB) recyclerView.getAdapter());
        adapter.clearList();
        adapter.addAll(vm);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Let me know if it gives any kind of error.

Comment: I wanted to answer the question of why it is happening. You're defining two different BindingAdapters with the same signatures and same attributes. One will always override the other and I think you may even see a warning, but I'm not entirely sure.

An alternative is to use a different attribute for the adapter property. (e.g. Activity A uses "bind:adaptera" and Activity B uses "bind:adapterb")

In this specific instance, you could also have both adapter implement an interface with clearList(), addAll(), and notifyDataSetChanged() and only cast to that interface.

Comment: @GeorgeMount Yes that's absolutely right, i just forgot option of different attributes, Thanks for suggestion.